# Seeding With TestDummy and Faker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and/or a better way of handling this situation.

Goals:

- To be able to insert myself as a user and also have 200 other users
  inserted into the database.
- Insert static data for myself into a separate table for profiles and random data for all other users into the database table.
- I'd like to find out why I keep getting a [InvalidArgumentException]
  Unknown formatter "password" error message when running my seed files in the console.

**UsersTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        User::create([
            'first_name' => 'Secret',
            'last_name' => 'Secret',
            'username' => 'secret',
            'email' => 'secret',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);

        TestDummy::times(200)->create('App\User');
    }

}
```

**UserProfilesTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;
use App\UserProfile;

class UserProfilesTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        UserProfile::create([
            'user_id' => '1',
            'avatar' => 'secret.jpg',
            'bio' => 'This is just my personal biography!',
            'address' => '1234 Secret Lane',
            'city' => 'Secret',
            'state' => 'Secret',
            'postcode' => '12345',
            'country' => 'United States',
            'phone' => '123-456-7890',
            'birthday' => '1988-09-04'
        ]);

        TestDummy::create('App\UserProfile');
    }

}
```

**Factories PHP File**

```
<?php

$factory('App\User', [
    'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
    'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
    'username' => $faker->userName,
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'password' => $faker->password
]);

$factory('App\UserProfile', [
    'user_id' => 'factory:App\User',
    'bio' => $faker->sentence(100),
    'avatar' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480),
    'address' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->address,
    'city' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->city,
    'state' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->state,
    'postcode' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->postcode,
    'country' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->country,
    'phone' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->phoneNumber,
    'birthday' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->dateTimeBetween('-40 years', '-18 years')
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a known version problem, when you install faker from composer package. See [this github thread](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/issues/441):

A workaround for this use the word formatter:

```
//factories
$factory('App\User', [
   'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
   'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
   'username' => $faker->userName,
   'email' => $faker->email,
   'password' => $faker->word
]);
```

Also I recommend you to hash passwords like a good practice even in test data, use the hash method:

```
App::make('hash')->make($faker->word);
```

Comment: I do hash my passwords inside the user model like so: public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($value);
    }

Comment: Only thing now is that doesn't solved my issue with the goals 1 and 2.

Comment: OmeCoatl Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The seeder throws you any error after the workaround implementation using $faker->word ? The logic you use for implement 1 and 2 seems to me very straight forward and must work.

Comment: I must be doing it wrong then because I"m not getting any desired results. Let me create a new stack question on it and repost.

Comment: OmeCoatI I created a new stack for you to check out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335397/attempt-at-seeding-with-faker-and-testdummy-for-efficiency