# Attempt At Seeding With Faker and TestDummy For Efficiency

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm wondering if I need to rethink how I'd seeding all my tables with my seeders. Is there a better more efficient way of handling all this data. After run my seed classes for some reason I have a total of 202 users. One is me and then 201 dummy users but there should be only 200 dummy users. I don't know where the extra user is getting made at.

Goals:

1. Create a user account only for me with supplied values for each
   field in the users table.
2. Create 200 additional uses in the database with dummy data with
   testdummy & faker.
3. Create a row for myself AND each of the other users to have a
   profile with supplied values for each field in the users profile
   table.
4. Create a row for myself AND each of the other users to have links to
   social networking pages with supplied values for each field in the
   users profile social links table.

**My Code Files**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        User::create([
            'first_name' => 'Secret',
            'last_name' => 'Secret',
            'username' => 'secret',
            'email' => 'secret@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);

        TestDummy::times(200)->create('App\User');
    }

}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;
use App\UserProfile;

class UserProfilesTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        UserProfile::create([
            'user_id' => '1',
            'avatar' => NULL
            'bio' => 'This is just my personal biography!',
            'address' => NULL
            'city' => NULL
            'state' => NULL
            'postcode' => NULL
            'country' => NULL
            'phone' => NULL
            'birthday' => NULL
        ]);

        TestDummy::create('App\UserProfile');
    }

}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;
use App\UserProfileSocialLinks;

class UserProfileSocialLinksTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        UserProfileSocialLinks::create([
            'user_id' => '1',
            'facebook_username' => NULL
            'twitter_username' => NULL
            'google_username' => NULL,
            'behance_username' => NULL,
            'pinterest_username' => NULL,
            'linkedin_username' => NULL
            'github_username' => NULL
            'youtube_username' => NULL
            'instagram_username' => NULL
            'external_link' => NULL
        ]);

        //TestDummy::create('App\UserProfileSocialLinks');
    }

}

<?php

$factory('App\User', [
    'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
    'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
    'username' => $faker->userName,
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'password' => $faker->word
]);

$factory('App\UserProfile', [
    'user_id' => 'factory:App\User',
    'bio' => $faker->sentence(100),
    'avatar' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480),
    'address' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->address,
    'city' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->city,
    'state' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->state,
    'postcode' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->postcode,
    'country' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->country,
    'phone' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->phoneNumber,
    'birthday' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->dateTimeBetween('-40 years', '-18 years')
]);

$factory('App\UserProfileSocialLinks', [
    'user_id' => 'factory:App\UserProfile',
    'facebook_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'twitter_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'google_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'behance_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'pinterest_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'linkedin_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'github_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'youtube_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName,
    'instagram_username' => $faker->optional($weight = 0.9)->userName
]);
```